# Are there any real limitations in Mono regarding ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono

I am a junior developer, doing my last year at college. I'm mostly asp.net oriented and even have a part time job coding in that language. I am interested on converting to linux and since visual studio is unsupported write my code in Mono.

Are there any notable limitations in Mono that I should be aware of (regarding ASP.NET)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say the biggest thing you lose is IIS.  ASP.net and IIS were very deeply linked.  Many of the advantages from ASP.net come from the utilization of hosting features in IIS.  The biggest one I can name is the ability of HTTP.sys to directly respond to a request in kernel mode if the page is in cache.  This means that the socket open is responded to immediately and can allow for orders of magnitude more hits to your webserver.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Mono website:

> Mono's ASP.Net does not implement the
>   following features:
>
> - Precompiled Websites
> - Webparts APIs.

Also most if not all 3rd party ASP.Net controls are not compatible with Mono unless otherwise specified. ComponentArt controls for example are not usable in Mono. However, there's no reason to think that this won't change as Mono gains popularity. ComponentArts has already mentioned that they are considering adding support in the future.

Comment: Precompiled websites are now supported in Mono, FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit of an edge case but Microsoft's [Web Service Enhancements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Enhancements) are [not supported](http://www.mono-project.com/WSE) on Mono. I ran into this problem trying to get some WSE services working on Mono.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding web services there are two very good open-source alternatives: [ServiceStack.Net](http://www.servicestack.net/) (using it) and [NANCY](http://nancyfx.org/).

These area a lot easier implement, use and maintain, IMHO, than services built on top of WCF.